# Existing package for managing a category field in the admin of a model?

Tags: django, foreign-keys, admin

I've got a model `MyModel` with a `category` field. The `Category` model has a ForeignKey to itself.

In the admin of MyModel I'd like to have the following:

1- a select box with the category instances having no parent, with the possibility to add one (the usual '+' button for a ForeignKey)

2- if the selected category has children, show another select box with the children, and the '+' button

3->2

Note: the number of subcategories is not fixed.

Is there any package that can do that? I can do it myself with some ajax, but it seems to be a common task, and I'd like to be sure there is no package to manage this easily.

Thanks

```
class Category(models.Model):

    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', related_name="children")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class MyModel(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is django-categories package, which add a select box with all category like:

[image]

https://github.com/callowayproject/django-categories